Unstaking from Phantom wallet
I am wanting to unstake my SOL from phantom. I have unstaked, and it is now sitting inactive. Whenever I click to withdraw stake, nothing happens the wheel keeps spinning.
Anyone have any idea what is going on here?... So far no support from Phantom at all, so hoping someone on here might he able to help.
Thanks

I’m facing the same issue. It’s been over a week since I stopped staking, and I still can’t withdraw or perform any activities with my Solana.

After unstaking you'll go through a cooldown period of about two days.
Don't worry, your funds are SAFE, it's the validator deactivating your stake after which you can safely close the stake account and get your SOL
As per the docs

A delegation or deactivation takes several epochs to complete, with a fraction of the delegation becoming active or inactive at each epoch boundary after the transaction containing the instructions has been submitted to the cluster.


There is also a limit on how much total stake can become delegated or deactivated in a single epoch, to prevent large sudden changes in stake across the network as a whole. Since warmup and cooldown are dependent on the behavior of other network participants, their exact duration is difficult to predict. Details on the warmup and cooldown timing can be found here.

more from the docs https://solana.com/docs/economics/staking/stake-accounts
